# Graph not showing in Python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code in Python for plotting a simple graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6):
    plt.plot(i, 2*i, linewidth = 3, label='$n = {i}$'.format(i=i))
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

When I execute it shows the window with the legend, but not the graph line. If I use `plt.scatter()` instead it plots the points normally. I was reading that it maybe an issue of the backend, but my matlibrc folder is empty and I don't have any config file there. Anyone with similar experience? Any ideas of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each 'line' only comprises one point at (i,2i). Using a line only, this does not result in anything. One can plot the point for example by adding the option `marker='o'` to the `plt.plot(...)` command.